# Which number cast is a registry Dword in vb?

Tags: vb.net, dword

Which number cast is a registry Dword in vb based on its minimum and max values?

I am trying to build an editor that can read and edit registry dumps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For VB.Net, you should use the `Integer` data type. See [this handy list](http://ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2001/07/30/vb7.html) for details on the available datatypes. In older Visual Basic, you would have used the `long` data type.

This has the proper number of bits (32; an x86 `DWORD` is a "double word", where a word is understood to be 16-bit), but I think there's a slight problem with VB not supporting "unsigned" values. This limitation might make presentation/editing a bit more complicated.

Comment: Nope, that’s wrong (at least for VB.NET, which is what the question is tagged as). `Long` in VB is 64 bits (maps to `System.Int64`) – also, VB *does* know unsigned data types (again: VB.NET).

Comment: A `Long` in VB.NET is a 64-bit value.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't catch the .net tag. Updated.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually fairly easy to find out:

```
Dim value As Object = Registry.GetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console", "FontSize", -1)
Console.WriteLine(value.GetType().FullName)
```

In the case of a REG_DWORD value this will print "System.Int32", which would be an `Integer` in VB.NET.